# How can I search product by entered keyword from entity in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am working on an ecommerce web application developed using Spring Boot as a back-end. There is a search box on the index page. From there, when a user visits my app and tries to search some product by entering any keyword inside the search box. So, if entered keyword matches with the entity then display the list of matched keyword results, and if not then display any error message. So, there are Category, Tag, Subcategory, Product entity from entered keyword should be matched and return JSON response to front-end.

Below is my controller to return entered keyword response:

```java
public ResponseEntity<?> searchbykeyword(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam("keyword") String keyword) {
  logger.info("Global search function is calling !!!");
  CustomResponse = ResponseFactory.getResponse(request);
  try {
    List<Product> text = null;
    List<Category> category = null;
    List<Tag> tag = null;
    List<Subcategory> subcategory = null;
    if(keyword != null) {
      System.out.println("Entered keyword is : || "+keyword);
      category = categoryDao.findByNameContains(keyword);
      
      tag = tagDao.findByNameContains(keyword);
      
      subcategory = subcategoryDao.findByNameContains(keyword);
      
      text = productdao.findByPrductnameContainsOrDescriptivenameContainsOrFlavorContainsOrCategoryOrTagOrSubcategory(keyword, keyword, keyword, category, tag, subcategory);
    }
    if (text != null) {
      CustomResponse.setResponse(text);
      CustomResponse.setStatus(CustomStatus.OK);
      CustomResponse.setStatusCode(CustomStatus.OK_CODE);
      CustomResponse.setResponseMessage(CustomStatus.SuccessMsg);
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    CustomResponse.setResponse(null);
    CustomResponse.setStatus(CustomStatus.Error);
    CustomResponse.setStatusCode(CustomStatus.Error_CODE);
    CustomResponse.setResponseMessage(CustomStatus.ErrorMsg);
  }
  return new ResponseEntity<ResponseDao>(CustomResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

The above code did not work as expected. I tried to figure it out too but did not get success.
If you have any ideas or suggestions then it would be helpful for me.

Comment: "_Above code did not working as expected._" So what you get actually and what you expected to get? Are the queries not working right? If the queries are not working correct you should post the code of your daos e.g. code from  `categoryDao.findByNameContains(keyword)`, `tagDao.findByNameContains(keyword);`, `subcategoryDao.findByNameContains(keyword);` , `productdao.findByPrductnameContainsOrDescriptivenameContainsOrFlavorContainsOrCategoryOrTagOrSubcategory(keyword, keyword, keyword, category, tag, subcategory);` etc

Comment: Please provide different different example for a given keyword what is expected and what actual response. If getting any error paste the stack-trace too.

Comment: I am not getting any error. Suppose I have entered cakes. Then I should get result in which 'cakes' is matched. Very common example is like Flipkart or Amazon. Whatever you type in search box, you able to get list of search result.

Comment: @Rakhi Ok, but where is your code that performs the queries? please edit your question and post the code of the daos as per my above comment.

Comment: @pleft Okay, sure I'll update my code.

Comment: We definitely need more code to help you. The issue might be in the implementation of the DAOs and not a Spring issue.

Comment: @JoãoDias Thank you. I have solved this thing.

Comment: Then please add your solution as an answer and then accept it as the correct one so that others may benefit from it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have changed below code :

```
@RequestMapping(value = AkApiUrl.searchbykeyword, method = { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET }, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
        public ResponseEntity<?> searchbykeyword(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session, @RequestParam("keyword") String keyword) {
            logger.info("Global search function is calling !!!");
            CustomResponse = ResponseFactory.getResponse(request);
        
            try {
                List<MappedCity> product = null;
                List<Product> text = null;
                List<Category> category = null;
                List<Tag> tag = null;
                List<Subcategory> subcategory = null;
                if(keyword != null) {
                    category = categoryDao.findByNameContainingIgnoreCase(keyword);
                    tag = tagDao.findByNameContainingIgnoreCase(keyword);
                    subcategory = subcategoryDao.findByNameContainingIgnoreCase(keyword);
                    text = productdao.findByPrductnameContainsIgnoreCaseOrDescriptivenameContainsIgnoreCaseOrFlavorContainsIgnoreCaseOrCategoryInOrTagInOrSubcategoryIn(keyword, keyword, keyword,category,tag,subcategory);
                    product = mappedcitydao.findTop5ByProductInAndStatusOrderByCreateddatetimeDesc(text, 1);
                }
                if (product != null) {
                    CustomResponse.setResponse(product);
                    CustomResponse.setStatus(CustomStatus.OK);
                    CustomResponse.setStatusCode(CustomStatus.OK_CODE);
                    CustomResponse.setResponseMessage(CustomStatus.SuccessMsg);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                CustomResponse.setResponse(null);
                CustomResponse.setStatus(CustomStatus.Error);
                CustomResponse.setStatusCode(CustomStatus.Error_CODE);
                CustomResponse.setResponseMessage(CustomStatus.ErrorMsg);
            }
            return new ResponseEntity<ResponseDao>(CustomResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
```